# Error in connecting aspx.cs to database situated in app_data folder [database connection error]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, vb.net

I am trying to connect database using asp.net, but I am getting following `Exception`:

> System.ArgumentException: Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.

```
objconn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB\v11.0);Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|test.mdf;User Instance=true;user id=xyz; password=xyz123; Initial Catalog=TEST";
```

Comment: Are you using VS 2012 with this and trying to attach to a SQL server?  I've run into a similar issue as this when setting up my server and coding environment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `localhost` as opposed to `(LocalDB\v11.0)`, like this?

```
objconn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|test.mdf;User Instance=true;user id=xyz; password=xyz123; Initial Catalog=TEST";
```

`localhost` will use TCP, while `(LocalDB\v11.0)` will use Named Pipes

Answer (score 0):

You use InitialCatalog & AttachedDBFile name Simultaneously.

```
objconn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|test.mdf;User Instance=true;user id=xyz; password=xyz123;
```

or

```
objconn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB\v11.0);Integrated Security=SSPI;User Instance=true;user id=xyz; password=xyz123; Initial Catalog=TEST";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
|DataDirectory|test.mdf
```

Should be

```
|DataDirectory|\test.mdf
```